# Alfresco - add item to existing workflow

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I need help with update workflowTask, add file to existing workflow.

My code is:

```
    List<NodeRef> addNodes = new ArrayList<NodeRef>();
    addNodes.add(addNodeRef);

    Map<QName, List<NodeRef>> nodesAdd = new HashMap<QName, List<NodeRef>>();
    nodesAdd.put(WorkflowModel.ASSOC_PACKAGE, addNodes);


    workflowService.updateTask(currentTask.getId(), null, nodesAdd, null);  //nullpointer
```

- currentTask is not null, is actual task in workflow, where I want add item
- addNodes is list actual NodeRef uploaded to alfresco folder
- addNodeRef is only one item uploaded to alfresco

Is there any other way an item is added to the already running workflow?

Where's my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add children to the package. Like this:

```
NodeRef packageNodeRef = ((ActivitiScriptNode)variables.get(bpm_package")).getNodeRef();
QName qname  = nodeService.getPrimaryParent(toAddNodeRef).getQName();
QName assocTypeQName = WorkflowModel.ASSOC_PACKAGE_CONTAINS;
nodeService.addChild(packageNodeRef, toAddNodeRef, assocTypeQName, qname);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
it works perfectly! 
thank you!